# S3 PHP putObject fails with 403, possible wrong file name

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Im trying to upload some files via a PHP script. The script was uploading everything well but suddenly got stuck on this specific file:

```
'/modules/chopinmol/input/CM_010217_164106_5892640295573/__MACOSX/Max-distelsa2017/._32LH570B_televisor(1).jpg'
```

Giving me the following error:

```
array (size=3)
  'code' => int 403
  'headers' => 
    array (size=8)
      'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' => string '' (length=0)
      'x-amz-request-id' => string 'ABE18DCEB2FE0522' (length=16)
      'x-amz-id-2' => string 'pMj/coQxdCMhVmQ0pA33qWhkPNs2K58xf/aeF3mP5/Ro/tS2yU94WoqC+0QHf930fUpbsafmd3A=' (length=76)
      'Content-Type' => string 'application/xml' (length=15)
      'Transfer-Encoding' => string 'chunked' (length=7)
      'Date' => string 'Mon, 27 Aug 2018 23' (length=19)
      'Connection' => string 'close' (length=5)
      'Server' => string 'AmazonS3' (length=8)
  'body' => string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>xxx</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20180827T230632Z
20180827/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request
299b3cf4620df5a94fdca4c2fc06e53bf93b6e5743433f0293247d24285bb40a</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>5a7557a5521a7591075302e52686254ebf5e82cb4be3ba72187bb741b4dcf7d7</'... (length=3650)
/var/www/html/chopinmol/modules/awscloudfronts3/classes/aws/AWSConnection.php:51:string 'PUT
/modules/chopinmol/input/CM_010217_164106_5892640295573/__MACOSX/Max-distelsa2017/._32LH570B_televisor(1).jpg

accept:*/*
cache-control:max-age=31536000, public
content-length:222
content-type:application/octet-stream
expect:100-continue
host:95278282c3887844a69b1f29e4cbcce5.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-acl:public-read
x-amz-content-sha256:a51b33110b0975da3524fa5dd82ef06d02d42353726075926046cbb95f466b5a
x-amz-date:20180827T230632Z

accept;cache-control;content-length;content-type;expect;host;x-amz-a'... (length=611)
```

On the rest of the previous files, the request had no problems executing succesfully. So my intution tells me it must be something with the file name.

Can anyone help me spot the problem?

This is the request if it helps:

URL:

```
'https://95278282c3887844a69b1f29e4cbcce5.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/modules/chopinmol/input/CM_010217_164106_5892640295573/__MACOSX/Max-distelsa2017/._32LH570B_televisor(1).jpg'
```

Headers:

```
array (size=10)
  'host' => string '95278282c3887844a69b1f29e4cbcce5.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' (length=59)
  'x-amz-date' => string '20180827T231403Z' (length=16)
  'Accept' => string '*/*' (length=3)
  'x-amz-acl' => string 'public-read' (length=11)
  'Content-Type' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
  'Cache-Control' => string 'max-age=31536000, public' (length=24)
  'Expect' => string '100-continue' (length=12)
  'Content-Length' => int 222
  'x-amz-content-sha256' => string 'a51b33110b0975da3524fa5dd82ef06d02d42353726075926046cbb95f466b5a' (length=64)
  'Authorization' => string 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx/20180827/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=accept;cache-control;content-length;content-type;expect;host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=xxx' (length=275)
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is - `SignatureDoesNotMatch -
 The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Comment: Yes, but why is the signature not matching for a specific file and for the rest of the files is working well. Is there a different process for signing depending on the file name?